# workaround a static method in a generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, generics, interface

I have a business model `TodoItem`. I have an API that gives me `todoitems`. So, I have a corresponding TodoItemModel for each controller (let's name it `TodoItemDTO`).

The `TodoItemDTO` class should be able to load itself from a `TodoItem` business class. So, usually, we would write a static method on the `TodoItemDTO` class `TodoItemDTO FromTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)`.

I would like to define an interface for such classes. But unfortunately I can't define a static method in an interface... (*note*: I use the latest C# version, so, finally, I do, but I should define it... however each class should define its static method)

Here is what I tried:

```
public interface IDtoModel<TBussinesModel, TDtoModel>
{
    TDtoModel FromBusinessModel(TBussinesModel businessObject);
}


public class ToDoItemDTO : IDtoModel<ToDoItem, ToDoItemDTO>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; private set; }

    public ToDoItemDTO FromBusinessModel(ToDoItem businessObject)
    {
        return new ToDoItemDTO()
        {
            Id = businessObject.Id,
            Title = businessObject.Title,
            Description = businessObject.Description,
            IsDone = businessObject.IsDone
        };
    }
}
```

The only 'problem' here is I have a **class** method that should be, normally, a **static** method.

So, by eg, when I define a generic controller, I need to create new objects without any need:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public abstract class BaseApiController<TBussinesModel, TDtoModel> : Controller
    where TBussinesModel : BaseEntity
    where TDtoModel : IDtoModel<TBussinesModel, TDtoModel>, new()        
{
    protected readonly IRepository _repository;
    public BaseApiController(IRepository repository) { _repository = repository; }

    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id)
    {
        var businessObject = await _repository.GetByIdAsync<TBussinesModel>(id);
        // 
        // here bellow, I need to create a new object
        // 
        var dtoObject = (new TDtoModel()).FromBusinessModel(businessObject);
        return Ok(dtoObject);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public abstract Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] TDtoModel item);
}
```

Comment: Define an abstract class that includes the implementation of the static method? C# has limitations.

Comment: 1) make that method a constructor. 2) make a new factory class. 3) create a dictionary of factory methods. 4) use reflection to build an expression tree to call the constructor.....

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, for the constructor; how do I define it in the interface?

Comment: Factory class with factory interface, if you **really** feel it will increase code understandableness, rather than complexity for the sake of it

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of options, none of them perfect.

Personally, I would start by turning your factory method into a constructor of the DTO;

```cs
    public ToDoItemDTO(ToDoItem businessObject)
    {
        Id = businessObject.Id;
        Title = businessObject.Title;
        Description = businessObject.Description;
        IsDone = businessObject.IsDone;
    }
```

You could define a factory class for each DTO. You could use `Activator.CreateInstance` to dynamically call the constructor at runtime.

Or you can locate the constructor with reflection, build an Expression tree and compile it.

```cs
    static Func<TBussinesModel, TDtoModel> GetFactory<TBussinesModel, TDtoModel>()
    {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TBussinesModel), "p");
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TBussinesModel, TDtoModel>>(
            Expression.New(
                typeof(TDtoModel).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(TBussinesModel) }),
                p
            ),
            p)
            .Compile();
    }
```

Comment: I am newbie in this kind of patterns... when you say "you could this; you could that" is like  "and" or "or"? I mean, are the sentences alternatives or just steps

Comment: Or. You want some "interface" that takes a business object and returns a dto. That could be an actual interface with a factory class. Or that "interface" could be a delegate. Or you could treat everything as object.